# USB Camera Powered After Shutdown in Windows 7 Only

Tags: usb, shutdown, camera

I have a dual boot Win 7/10 Shuttle XPC system, with a Point Grey USB Camera.  When I shut down from Win10 the camera powers off.  When I shut down from Win7 it remains on.  I would like it to lose power under Win7 as well.

EuP is enabled, fast boot is disabled.  My phone doesn't charge from this port after shutdown, it is just this USB camera that seems to remain on after shutdown and only when I shut down from Win7.

Is there anything else I should try?  Thanks!

Comment: Based on what you're describing, it sounds to me like the Windows 10 camera driver issues a power-off command to the camera, whereas the Windows 7 driver does not.  You may have to depend on the manufacturer to provide an updated windows 7 driver that behaves this way.  If you pull the USB cable out (while Windows 10 is running) does the camera shut off?  If not, then I'd definitely think it's software that's powering it off.

Comment: If I pull out the cable it definitely shuts off, it is powered via USB.  I just called the camera manufacturer, who says that their driver doesn't send any messages during shutdown.  But their support person might not actually know the answer.

Comment: How is it set in the power management for the device driver? In the windows "device manager", selecting the device and going to the "power management" tab.  Also you could "View" menu  "devices by connection" and check all (such fun) the power management for the whole connection path which would include the Usb Hub items.

Comment: Sorry I missed your comment!  The camera has no Power Management options in Device Manager.  All USB controllers have "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power" checked and "Allow this device to wake the computer" unchecked.